# Unexpected issuerAssignedId when trying to configure multi-tenant login using custom policies for Azure B2C

Tags: identityserver4, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, identity-experience-framework

I have an existing IdentityServer4 installation that is used to federate users between things like Google & Microsoft into a single login identity. In my situation, there are no local user credentials/passwords. Just the identity with an associated external provider. I'm trying to migrate to using Azure B2C and am hitting some roadblocks.

I've found that if I use the same ClientId and ClientSecret that IdentityServer is configured with, then I get the same IDs for users when signing in via an external identity provider. Which is great because I need them to be the same in order to try and migrate accounts over by reading them from the existing MSSQL database, and importing into Azure B2C using MS Graph.

I need to allow both Microsoft work accounts, as well as personal ones. So I need to use custom policies to allow for a [multi-tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) configuration, since the built in provider doesn't support this.
However as soon as I flip my implementation over from the built in user flows and provider, to using custom policies, I don't get the expected `issuerAssignedId` anymore. Originally, the IDs looked something like `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHGFdaj94jfdsgjifdh4ngd` (made up, but you get the idea). Now with the custom policies, the `issuerAssignedId` being recorded in the B2C user looks like a GUID. So not just a different value, but a total different format. Am I missing something here? What would happen if someone has an fully operational AzureB2C install with built in functionality, and later identified a need to move to custom policies. How would users ever be able to look into their existing accounts with an external identity provider?

My `TechnicalProfile` for the multi-tenant sign is is essentially copy/pasted from their documentation, so I'm not sure what the deal is here?

Comment: In user flow I think the objectId from the external IdP is base64 encoded and becomes issuerAssignedId. But in custom policy, the issuerAssignedId is equal to the objectId coming from the external IdP.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be base64? At least it doesn't have the tell tale sign of ending in an `=`?  If I add the assumedly missing `=`, I can decode it and get a 32 byte array with the first 16 being `0`'s (explains the repeated `A`'s). But if I try to use the trailing 16 bytes with the `Guid` constructor, I get a Guid that doesn't match what I expected. The `issuerAssignedId` that gets saved if I register a new account in AzureB2C with the same Microsoft account, that saved Guid looks something like `00000000-0000-0000-eaa1-209e59217e32`. So I'm not sure if I'm on the right track with that or not

Comment: Is there not a migration path if some one has an existing AxureB2C, and later has to switch to using custom policies with IEF? I was hoping the samples/examples on github would replicate the built in user flows exactly to serve as a starting point, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: They really should replicate, let me look into it.

Comment: Much appreciated, any help you can provide would save much of my remaining sanity 

Comment: Did you make any discoveries regarding this?